# HTMl video tag is not working on range of byte stream

Tags: html, stream, streaming, nodes

I created video streaming server in nodejs. for video streaming, I used the range byte streaming technique. But at client side i.e. on the browser not able to render that video. Here I provide the code. here movie1.mp4 file of 10mb.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/movie1.mp4') {
          var movie_mp4 = fs.readFileSync('movie1.mp4');
          var total = movie_mp4.length;
          var range = req.headers.range;

        console.log("range"+range)
            var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);

            var chunksize = 10000;
            var end = start + chunksize; //positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
             if(total < end){
                 end = total-1;
                  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total, 
                                     "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                                     "Content-Length": (end-start),
                                     "Content-Type":"video/mp4"});
                res.end(movie_mp4.slice(start, end), "binary");
             }else{
                res.writeHead(206, { "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total, 
                                     "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                                     "Content-Length": (end-start),
                                     "Content-Type":"video/mp4"});
                res.end(movie_mp4.slice(start, end), "binary");
             }           
    }   
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write('<html>     <title>Welcome</title>     <body>' );
            res.write('<video controls preload="auto">             <source src="movie1.mp4"  type="video/mp4"/>   </video>');
            res.write('</body> </html>');
            return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: First to help you in this context i need : Environment device, OS, Browser using or targeting?

Comment: OS: Windows, Browser : Chrome,

Comment: try to configure your header like this HTTP/1.1, Content-Range: bytes 0-12345 force this range to test. did you tested you vars start and end wich values ??

Comment: I sent whole content same time to browser then it runs

Comment: Ok so you left partial header?

Comment: Means I don't get you?

Comment: It's mean you if don't use the content-range:bytes, for sending whole content in the same time. The goal here on the streaming way is to restrict or  seek or ... your videos by using the way of "range of max bytes in queues, you can easy get metadata, known the the time out session of users , the timeline of the video (how many minutes watching, to add pub ...etc ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155711/discussion-between-dnyanesh-and-headmax).

Comment: sorry i didn't see it i was away time diner.